# How to read alphanumeric data from Excel Cell using HSSF?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an `Excel file` containing values of following `data types` `String`, `Boolean`, `Numeric` and `Alpha Numeric`. Using `HSSF poi`, I extracted the same.

```
cell.getStringCellValue();  //for String values
cell.getBooleanCellValue(); //for Boolean values True or False
cell.getNumericCellValue(); //for Numeric values.
```

Can anyone please help me to fetch data of `alphanumeric` data from a Excel cell value?

FYI :

Following are the available constants in `HSSF poi`,

```
Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK
Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA
Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN
Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR
```

Comment: Isn't alpha numeric a subset of String? Doesn't cell.getStringCellValue() work?

Comment: Hi Eran, I tried fetching it using cell.getStringCellValue(), but then it threw the floowing exception "at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:643)". Type mismatch.

Comment: Why aren't you fetching the type, and then use that to work out what value to fetch? (See the [Apache POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) for more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the following way,

```
int cellType = cell.getCellType();
switch(cellType)
{
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
          //
          cell.get
          break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
          //
          cellValue = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
          break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
          //
          break;

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
          //
          break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
          //
          cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
          break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
          //
          cellValue = cell.RichStringCellValue();
          break;
}
```